# Find causes for slower elasticsearch responses

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have been using elasticsearch for an e-commerce site for quite some time - not only for search, but also to retrieve product data (/index/type/{id}) to avoid SQL queries.

Generally this works really well and most requests are answered between 1ms and 3ms. But there are some requests which take 100ms-250ms - just for a GET request like /index/type/{id}, where no actual searching is done and which normally takes 1-2ms. It seems to me that something must be wrong if such a response takes more than 100ms, because the server has a lot of RAM & a fast 6-core-CPU, the data is stored on very fast SSDs, there are only 150'000 entries (about 300MB in Elasticsearch) and there is almost no load. Elasticsearch has 5GB of RAM, and there is enough spare RAM for Lucene to cache all entries all the time. Requests are made through a local network with a dedicated switch. The index has only one shard and I am running Elasticsearch 2.3.

I am doing the requests in PHP. I have already tried using Nginx as reverse proxy for Elasticsearch, but this did not solve anything - it happens with and without Nginx inbetween.

**Edit**: Slow requests happen about 1% of the time (in relation to total number of requests). I can also reproduce it by just making 1000 requests in PHP to /index/type/{id} in Elasticsearch - always 1% will be really slow, even when using the same ID like /index/type/55 (as long as the ID exists). This also means there is no "cache effect" - after the first request Elasticsearch should have the data "ready", yet the number of slow requests is the same no matter what IDs I request or if I request the same ID over and over.

**Edit2**: I have looked at the stats of my nodes with Marvel & Kibana, and nothing indicates slowdowns there: between 20-40% of JVM heap memory is used, and almost no latency (between 0.1ms and 0.5ms). It confirms that there are more than enough resources and I see no correlations or hints for the cause of any slow requests.

**After a lot of testing:**

These are now my definite testing results:

- The larger the response from Elasticsearch, the more likely slow requests are going to happen. Many small responses have a MUCH larger chance of not being exceptionally slow than one large response.
- Bombarding Elasticsearch with simple GET requests reduces the likelihood of slow responses when I run more requests in parallel.
- When using a simple search for one keyword over and over again, Elasticsearch tells me in the response it "took" 2-3ms, even when a response takes 200ms until my application receives it. But also here: the larger the response, the higher the chances are of slow responses. 1KB response is never slow when I run loops of requests, 2.5KB is only a little slow (30ms) in very few instances, 10KB response always has up to 1% of slow requests with up to 200ms.

I have taken into account that it might be a network "problem", especially when Elasticsearch thinks it is fast even when it is slow. But it would be a strange root cause, because my setup is so standard (Debian Jessie). Also, keep-alive connections and TCP_NODELAY do nothing to improve this problem.

Anybody know how to find the root cause, and what could possibly be happening?

Comment: This may be totally unrelated, but it's something... I use AWS CloudSearch, RDS, EC2/BeanStalk and ElastiCache and I've been seeing 200ms delays on various DNS lookups recently.

Comment: Where is your 100-200ms delay seen from? full browser round trip through your application or direct endpoint to the AWS search services?

Comment: I am using my own servers (colocation) - the measurements are taken within PHP, where I measure how long every request to Elasticsearch takes, just in case it takes too long. No DNS lookups, I access the server IPs directly.

Comment: as a suggestion, analyze the memory of JVM on these glitches. Perhaps you may have to manually configure memory of JVM.

Comment: How do you mean that? I am using the Oracle JVM - what can I configure except the amount of memory used by Elasticsearch?

Comment: For those interested to follow, @iquito has also posted this question [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17451) and [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/get-api-requests-sometimes-slow-up-to-200ms-instead-of-2ms/46301)

Comment: How many data nodes and master nodes you have in your elastic search cluster?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the reason for the measureable slow responses: It was the network driver or maybe even the hardware implementation on the network card.

When running tests from the node itself the slow responses disappeared, and I also noticed the older servers (8 years old compared to the only-2-years-old newer servers) had no slow responses when running tests on them, which indicated the requesting server was at fault, not the responding ES server, but it also indicated the network itself was fine, because only the "new" servers had this problem.

I went down the rabbit hole of TCP/network settings and found ethtool, which shows network configuration and also allows to change it. I learned there was something called "offloading", where a lot of network operations are offloaded to the network card (especially splitting up requests and responses into segments), and tried the following command to disable all offloading:

```
ethtool -K eth1 tx off rx off sg off tso off ufo off gso off gro off lro off rxvlan off txvlan off rxhash off
```

Afterwards my request-1000-identical-searches-from-ES were as fast as expected - no slow requests anymore. My network card (Intel® 82574L Dual port GbE LAN on a SuperMicro X9SRL-F running the e1000e driver) seems to do something in hardware which slows down responses, or holds them back, or whatever. The older servers are running the tg3 driver - offloading is enabled on them (according to ethtool), but it does not cause these delayed responses. Disabling offloading had no noticeable effect on CPU load, which is probably to be expected with any modern CPUs.

With the new settings, I was able to lower the number of slow pages due to slow Elasticsearch responses to 0.07%, where before it was about 1%. I also noticed that using Nginx as reverse proxy for Elasticsearch caused some slow responses, even though they were not many - usually about 3-5 responses for every 150'000 were above 50ms. Without Nginx, by just querying Elasticsearch directly, I am now unable to reproduce any slow requests anymore, even at a grand scale.

**UPDATE 11/2017**

After updating to Debian Stretch and running the server with kernel 4.9 all remaining "slow requests" disappeared. So this problem seems to be at least partly rooted in older linux kernels.